# How to create a char array of variable length in powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to create a char array of length $Count in powershell?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Count
415
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $chars = New-Object System.Char ($Count)
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Char.
At line:1 char:10
+ $chars = New-Object System.Char ($Count)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

I tried 
[Char[]] $chars = @(415)
```

I had a class which needed a char array, but I basically I found a solution to my problem by using Strings. But I just wanted to ask if any one knows how to create an empty char array of variable length.

Eg: How do I do this in powershell? C# -> var chars = new Char[Count];

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I populate an array of unkown length in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860830/how-do-i-populate-an-array-of-unkown-length-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell 5.0, you can use the [`new()` constructor method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn820211.aspx):

```
PS C:\> $Count = 415
PS C:\> $chars = [char[]]::new($Count)
PS C:\> $chars.Count
415
```

In earlier versions, use the [`New-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849885(v=wps.620).aspx), and indicate that you want an array with `[]`:

```
$chars = New-Object -TypeName 'char[]' -ArgumentList $Count
```

Comment: You could also use `[Array]::CreateInstance([char],415)`.

Comment: Thanks. The 2 methods provided by Mathias and one by PetSerAl all work!

Comment: @ComedianNinja If this answered your question, please accept the answer (check box below the up/down voting buttons on the left).